# How to obtain the result of a transaction in the Firebase database?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise, angular2-services

I'm trying to get the result of an **update** operation on a node of the Firebase Database, working with Angular2. 
This method is executed in a *service class* called *arbitro.service.ts*.

This class has a **items** attribute, that allows executing get, insertion and update operations on Firebase Database:

```
items: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
```

The code that was used to perform the update on *Arbitro* record is shown below:

```
  editarArbitro(arbitro: Arbitro): void {
    this.items.update(arbitro.id, arbitro);
  }
```

This method, receives as parameter an instance of *Arbitro* class and executes the update in the Firebase database.

By analyzing the methods applicable to *update* operation, I discovered **then** method.
I attach a capture showing the necessary parameters for the **then** implementation.

[image: then method]

The return of the then method is an object of type:

```
firebase.Promise<any>
```

As I investigated, this **Promise** element, returns the code of the result of the transaction on the database.

My question is: 
is it possible to use this **Promise** element to know if a transaction ended successfully or failed? 
How should I handle the return of the update function?

Regards!

Comment: It should work just like any other promise, which resolves with the work is complete and rejects if there's an error.  Use `then()` chained with  `catch()` to handle those cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Doug commented, a Promise can result in two states: either the operation completes successfully, in which case the promise is *resolved* and its `then()` callback is called, or the operation fails, in which the promise is *rejected* and its `catch()` callback is called.

So you can handle both with:

```
this.items.update(arbitro.id, arbitro)
    .then(function() {
        console.log("Update completed successfully");
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Update failed: "+error);
    });
```